# how to make a sql table using a synonym list?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making a table by using a synonym list.

I have 3 different tables, input, synonym list and the output.

The structure of the input is different, the output and the synonyms are the same.
In the synonym list are the synonyms of the possible names of the input.
The goal of using this synonym list is switching the input to output.

Now is the question, what is the best method for doing this?
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management studio 2016

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWqj8.jpg)

Comment: Show us the structure of the tables

Comment: With an insert statement?

Comment: are you really using ms-query?  I don't think so, removed it.

Comment: provide us with sample data and with expected outcome

Comment: @SeanLange no, i have the tables in the database i think i need a select statement.

Comment: @GuidoG i include a new image with the structure of the table !

Comment: Here is the problem. We can't see your screen, we have no idea what your table structures are, we have no idea what you are trying to accomplish. All we have is an extremely vague description of a problem. In short, what you really need first is a complete question. Then and only then can other help provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
InputTable
  word varchar(50)

OutputTable
  word varchar(50)
```

then

```
SynTable
  in varhcar(50)
  out varchar(50)
```

And you would get your output like this

```
INSERT INTO OutputTable
  SELECT SynTable.out
  FROM InputTable
  JOIN SynTable ON InputTable.word = SynTable.in
```

Homework is fun.

Comment: thanks for your help, it works but what my intention was  that it's searches on column name and that it inserts the rows in the output under the right column

Comment: @MatsDekker -- that is what my answer does.  The "search" is called a join in SQL

Comment: I want him to take the whole row. And move the whole row to the right row. For example, everyting under size needs to move under product_size. Thanks for helping!